# Node.js service: Getting "Cannot GET /<path>" after POST request in microservice (works locally)

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

I've created a node.js microservice using the libraries express and request.

The idea is to forward a post-request by the client application from the first endpoint ("http://example.com/proxy/x") to the second one ("http://example.com/x"). If I do the request to /proxy/x via POSTMAN locally to my "localhost:/proxy/x" instance, it works just fine. The request gets the expected response without any problem. If I push it to the cloud environment using a containering system and ask the endpoint via "http://example.com/proxy/x" it says "CANNOT /GET /x" and fails with a 404 error.

1. To cover the "404" error, I've even created a app.get listener on "/proxy/x". 
   Now it returns "error = true". That means my POST is turned to a GET call.
2. The url is already hardcoded, before I've generated it with a combination of req.protocol and req.get('host'). Seems to generate a valid url, still does not work.

POST http://example.com/proxy/target

```
app.post('/proxy/target', (req, res) => {
    // const currentURL = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
    const requestBody = req.body;
    request.post({
        url: 'http://example.com/target',
        followAllRedirects: true, // I've also tried to outcomment it 
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Authorization': 'Basic user:password',
        },
        form: requestBody
      },
      (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        } else {
          // console.dir(response);
          return res.status(response.statusCode).send(response.body);
        }
      }
    );
}); 


app.route('/target')
  .post(function (req, res) { 
    //some code 
});
```

Expected result should be the response body the call delivers, if I'm callign /target directly.

{ 
  'success':true
}

It actually is responding with: 
Cannot GET /x/

As it works perfectly on my localhost, it might be the case that my cloud dev environment is the problem.

I would be glad for additional ideas. The cloudsystem is a containering environment called CloudFoundry.

*Update:* 
It seems like CloudFoundry is using NGINX per default: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/nginx/index.html 
Other developers had similar issues when using NGINX: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/post-request-redirects-to-get-in-nginx-proxy-and-nodejs

Comment: I don't know if it's allowed that I self answer my question, but indeed it seems to be a thing related to NGINX and not to my code. The server has changed the request method from POST to GET whenever the endpoint was called via http://. So simply adding and "s" to "req.protocol" did the trick and now it also works after deploying the application to the cloud. Of course that is just a hotfix.

Comment: `It seems like CloudFoundry is using NGINX per default` -> That is only partially true. You *can* use Nginx, if you want. There is a buildpack that will provide it. You have not provided any output from deploying to CF, so it's not possible to know what buildpack(s) you are using. Please include the full output of `cf push`, as that will provide context for what you are doing. Please also provide `cf logs`, it may not know anything but know that is helpful too.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but it is definetely NGINX as OUT says ```Installing nginx``` and ```Using nginx version 1.15.12``` in my log.

Comment: OK, if you could include the full output that would be helpful. I wouldn't normally expect to see Nginx being installed by the Node.js buildpack. Since you mentioned running a Node.js app, I'd expect that buildpack to be running. The `cf push` command (and manifest.yml) and full output would confirm and enable more people to help you.